# Printing JsonObject in Spring cloud using Kafka Binder

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I am new to Spring Cloud and kafka stream. I am trying to setup spring cloud application with kafka binder. I tried testing kafka stream processor locally but I am unable to print any logs.

My kafka message will contain JSONObject. kafkaStreamListener class is :

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaStreamListener {

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(KafkaStreamListener.class);
    
    //bean for processing autonomous messages 
     @Bean
      public Function<KStream<String, JSONObject>, KStream<String, JSONObject>> autonomousProcessor() {
         System.out.println("start of stream processor%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%**************************");
         logger.info("inside processor");
         return kstream -> kstream.filter((key,value) -> {
         System.out.println(value.toString()); 
         return true;});
             }
```

Application.properties :

```
#Processor group with inputs and outputs
spring.cloud.stream.function.definition = autonomousProcessor
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.autonomousProcessor-in-0.destination = INPUT_TOPIC
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.autonomousProcessor-out-0.destination = OUTPUT_TOPIC
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.functions.autonomousProcessor.application-id= autonomousProcessorGroup
```

Issue :
In Debug mode, breakpoint reaches filter step directly and than no action. It skips the logger and SOP. Not sure what maybe the issue .
Spring cloud version : Hoxton.SR11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are seeing is the right behavior. Your function will be invoked by the binder at the bootstrap time only once and then the initial SOP and logger will be called (again only once). You will see them get called if you set a breakpoint on the first SOP or logger when starting the app. Then when the Kafka topic receives data, the provided lambda (with filter) will be called. The internal SOP in your filter should log `value.toString()` on each invocation of the filer per record.

Comment: But nothing is getting printed actually. Console is empty.

Comment: Feel free to share a small sample application on Github where the issue can be reproduced. That way we can triage the issue further.

Comment: Hello @sobychacko , i shared a sample application here https://github.com/Jasveen-singh/springCloudKafkaStream/tree/feature/KafkaStreamSampleApp . I am unable to get any messages to print in console or logs

Comment: How do you send data to the input topic for testing?

Comment: I am using a local kafka and wrote a simple kafka producer to send data to it

Comment: I have added a sample producer app which I am using with same json which I am publishing inside the package.

Comment: Yes, I see your note on deserialization. It seems like something goes wrong with deserializing JSONObject. Could you debug and see where it falls apart? Maybe you need to provide a custom deserializer for that and wrap it in a Serde? In any case, see if you can write a simple application that consumes JSONObject without involving Kafka Streams and make it deserialize successfully.

Comment: Thanks, I tried with standard consumer too. Seems an issue with JsonDeserializer only. I will check for custom deserializer. I can manage with receiving String as input But My response will be  JSONObject. Is it possible to have different input aand output formats in Stream? Do you have any example where we have different data types for input and output in stream?

Comment: Sure, we can have different types as input/output. Take a look at some examples here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/main/kafka-streams-samples